# What does finding the limits of a truncated value mean?

Tags: math, truncation, approximate

X_hat is an approximation of X. It is given by the X_t, the truncation of X using t bits.

**Find the limits of X_t / X.**

X_hat and X_t are represented in floating-point binary.
From my understand:

```
If t = 3 and X_hat = 1, X_t = 1.01
```

1/1 = 1 is the upper limit? What about the lower limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes the question is about *significant* bits (for an example in decimal, `3141592` truncated to 3 significant digits would be `3140000`, and truncated to 5 significant digits would be `3141500`). Since the question is about the relative error, it does not matter whether or where there is a decimal point, so it can be assumed without loss of generality that the numbers are integers.

If `X = 0` then `X̂ = X = 0` and `X̂ / X` is undefined.

Otherwise, if `0 < X < 2^(t-1)` then `X` has at most `t-1` significant bits, and truncation leaves `X` unchanged, so `X̂ = X` and `X̂ / X = 1`.

Otherwise, if `X >= 2^(t-1)` then `X` can be written as `X = 2^n q + r` where `n >= 0`, `2^(t-1) <= q < 2^t` and `0 <= r < 2^n`. The leftmost `t` bits of `X` are `q`, so the truncation of `X` to `t` significant bits is `X̂ = 2^n q`.

Then `X̂ / X = 2^n q / (2^n q + r) = 1 - 1 / (1 + r / (2^n q))`. The expression is decreasing in `r` and increasing in `q`, which combined with `r < 2^n` and `q >= 2^(t-1)` gives the lower bound:

```
X̂ / X  >  2^(n+t-1) / (2^(n+t-1) + 2^n)
       =  1 - 1 / (1 + 2^(t-1))
```

For a fixed `n > 0` the exact lower bound derived from `r <= 2^n - 1` and `q >= 2^(t-1)` is:

```
X̂ / X  >=  2^(n+t-1) / (2^(n+t-1) + 2^n - 1)
        =  1 - (2^n - 1) / (2^(n+t-1) + 2^n - 1)
        =  1 - 1 / (1 + 2^(n+t-1) / (2^n - 1))
        =  1 - 1 / (1 + 2^(t-1) / (1 - 1 / 2^n))
```

This lower bound is attained for `X = 2^(n+t-1) + 2^n - 1` corresponding to `X̂ = 2^(n+t-1)`. In the limit `n → ∞` it reduces to the lower bound independent of `n` derived at the previous step.